# Can a C# Property ever have no GetMethod and no SetMethod

Tags: c#, reflection, linq-expressions, propertyinfo

Browsing the .NET core source code  for System.Linq.Expressions, I found the following code located [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/MemberExpression.cs#L286-L298):

```
MethodInfo mi = property.GetGetMethod(true);
if (mi == null)
{
    mi = property.GetSetMethod(true);
    if (mi == null)
    {
        throw Error.PropertyDoesNotHaveAccessor(property, nameof(property));
    }
}
```

Is there any way that `GetGetMethod` **and** `GetSetMethod` can both return null, as seems to be accounted for here? Is this dead code?
The C# compiler doesn't allow for a property to have no getter and no setter, so how is this possible for `PropertyInfo`.

My motivation is to contribute to the OSS code by adding test coverage, so I'm trying to see what test cases would cover this

Comment: Perhaps it's possible to achieve this by manually writing IL instead of C#?

Comment: Not sure.  I always thought c# properties were just helpers for compiler-generated _get and set methods_.

Comment: `GetGetMethod` returns "A MethodInfo object representing the public get accessor for this property, **or null if the get accessor is non-public** or does not exist." - maybe that's why. Can you link to the source you're referring to?

Comment: @Blorgbeard updated the question to include a link. Also, this is passing a parameter to find non-public accessors

Comment: Your assumption that C# is relevant is not very accurate.  Linq works for *any* language that can target .NET.  There are dozens.  That a .NET framework method should *never* throw NullReferenceException is something that every programmer can sympathize with :)

Comment: Have a look at ECMA-335 Partition II.17, it states: *A property can contain any number of methods in its body.* Also you can find there the concept of `.other` methods, that is not exposed in C# and from C# only accessible using reflection.

Comment: @thehennyy do you know how this can be achieved?

Comment: Do you mean creating an `.other` method? You can do this for example by using the ILAssembler or methods in the `Reflection.Emit` namespace. To access such a method in C# using reflection there is the `PropertyInfo.GetAccessors` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [CLI Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf),

> CLS Rule 28: Properties shall adhere to a specific naming pattern. See
>   §I.10.4. The SpecialName attribute referred to in CLS rule 24 shall be
>   ignored in appropriate name comparisons and shall adhere to identifier
>   rules. A property shall have a getter method, a setter method, or
>   both.

That's on page 52 of the linked PDF.

That seems to say that one or the other must be there.

It appears that the developer decided to interpret the specification that way, and acted accordingly in the face of invalid data. Seems like quite a reasonable thing to do.

It might be possible, by writing IL or by editing the metadata afterwards, to create a property that has no getter or setter. And the .NET loader might go ahead and load it anyway, even if it is considered an invalid property. I've seen that kind of thing happen in other fields.

With that in mind, code that handles the "impossible" situation of a property with neither getter nor setter doesn't seem like dead code to me.

Comment: Thanks for the digging around. So this *is* dead code for anyone using C#, but perhaps not in other languages?

Comment: @HBellamy: I'm not familiar enough with LINQ expressions or how they're used to say whether that's true. If all you're working with is code that you wrote in C#, then your statement is probably true. But if you reference classes in assemblies that you didn't create, then it seems like it's relevant to you, as well.

Comment: "The CLS is a set of rules intended to promote language interoperability." It's not something that a library *has to* adhere to, to be valid. So basing this answer based on a CLS rule does not make much sense to me.

Comment: @svick: Okay, I can accept that. So if the CLS is more a list of guidelines than it is a contract, then the answer to the OP's stated question is "Yes: a property *can* have no getter and no setter." In which case the code in question is not dead code. Funny: my reasoning is perhaps suspect, but the answer is right.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a property with no accessors in IL:

```
.class public C
{
  .property int32 Count() { } 
}
```

Which can then trigger the code path you mentioned:

```
var prop = typeof(C).GetProperty("Count", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

Expression.Property(null, prop);
```

This code throws:

> ArgumentException: The property 'Int32 Count' has no 'get' or 'set' accessors

Answer (score 2):

After some research, there is a way to achieve this, via System.Reflection.Emit

```
AssemblyBuilder assembly = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Name"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
ModuleBuilder module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("Module");

TypeBuilder type = module.DefineType("Type");
PropertyBuilder property = type.DefineProperty("Property", PropertyAttributes.None, typeof(void), new Type[0]);

Type createdType = type.CreateType();
PropertyInfo createdProperty = createdType.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.First();

Console.WriteLine(createdProperty.GetGetMethod(true) == null);
Console.WriteLine(createdProperty.GetSetMethod(true) == null);
```

This is obviously a strange way to have no setter or getter without IL